# Error retrieving glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 on successful AJAX call from jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I get an error message saying that jQuery couldn't find the path to the glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2. The error shows up when the function for successful AJAX request is ran. In that function I inserted a hyperlink that uses a glyphicon from Twitter Bootstrap.

Looking at the path, I am sure that it is the correct path so I don't know why it's giving me the error. How could I fix this error?

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: How are you accessing this page (what http server)? Have you tried opening the URL directly? What are the permissions on the fonts directory and this specific file?

Comment: I accessed the page through IIS Express. I have tried to open the URL directly and received 404 message. The permission is the same with the folder that contains glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff file, so it should be ok.

Comment: If you cannot access the URL directly, you won't be able to do it with an AJAX call. Verify the file exists and that you don't have any typos in the URL / filename.

Comment: The screenshot that I attached shows that I do have the file in the right path.

Comment: @JohanGunawan How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 75):

Using IIS I fixed it inside the Web.config-file, add the following inside `<system.webServer>`:

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

Notice I remove the extensions first, in case they already exist.

Comment: Should final line be `<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />`?

Answer (score 54):

To get it to work with IIS Express you need to add the mime type. In a text editor open the file in your Documents folder at `%UserProfile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

Search for a line that looks like this:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
```

I would recommend changing it as the official MIME type has changed, but regardless simply copy that line and add a new one and change the fileExtension to .woff2 in the new one. Here is my modified file (with the corrected MIME types)

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
```

Comment: This solved my issue in IIS after i added woff2 mime type site started to load woff2 fonts.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer to work in the IIS GUI or aren't comfortable with command line or config files, follow the steps below.

To resolve the *error retrieving glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2* in IIS, you just need to add a MIME type for ***woff2***.

1. *Open* IIS and *Select* your server
2. In the **Features View**, select **MIME Types**
3. Click **Add...** in the **Actions** pane (top-right corner)
4. Enter the **File name extension** of ***.woff2***
5. Enter the **MIME type** of ***application/font-woff***

Also, as [palehorse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312/palehorse) noted, ensure the MIME type for both ***.woff*** and ***.woff2*** are ***application/font-woff***

*Sources:*

- [TechNet - Add a MIME Type (IIS 7) Tutorial](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [W3 - Official MIME Media Type Registration](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b)

Comment: The GUI's always going to be the safest place to do these things. +1